# Escape # symbol in jinja variable assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, jinja2

I want to assign a hex color code to a variable in a yaml that will get parsed with jinja2. However, string "#558dd5" evaluates to None because of the # symbol. Without it, it evaluates to "558dd5".

example yaml:

```
{% set colors = namespace() %}
{% set colors.blue = "#558dd5" %}


"colors":
  "blue": {{colors.blue}}
```

One solution that I found that is working is changing it to

```
{% set colors.blue = "#558dd5"|tojson %}
```

which works but is really ugly. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This evaluate to none because you are using `colors.focus_blue` but setting `colors.blue`. If I try with `"blue": {{colors.blue}}`, I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Sorry, edited that typo. Are you not able to reproduce? Colleagues of mine were. Using python 3.7 and jinja2 3.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated YAML will look like this:

```yaml
"colors":
  "blue": #558dd5
```

This makes `#558dd5` a comment. To avoid this, surround the Jinja replacement command with quotes:

```yaml
{% set colors = namespace() %}
{% set colors.blue = "#558dd5" %}


"colors":
  "blue": "{{colors.blue}}"
```

Now you'll get

```yaml
"colors":
  "blue": "#558dd5"
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the behaviour behind the issue. Problem is indeed solved this way and the solution makes sense.